# how to go along with this code android

Tags: android, android-intent, exif

This is the code to extract tags from jpeg.i take picture by calling camera intent. after clicking photo i should send it to below code for extracting information. How to send the clicked photo as argument?

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(null != bundle)
{
     String filepath = bundle.getString(FILE_PATH_KEY);

     try 
     {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filepath);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.append("Date & Time: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME) + "\n\n");
        builder.append("Flash: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH) + "\n");
        builder.append("Focal Length: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH) + "\n\n");
        builder.append("GPS Datestamp: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH) + "\n");
        builder.append("GPS Latitude: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE) + "\n");
        builder.append("GPS Latitude Ref: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF) + "\n");
        builder.append("GPS Longitude: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE) + "\n");
        builder.append("GPS Longitude Ref: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF) + "\n");
        builder.append("GPS Processing Method: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD) + "\n");
        builder.append("GPS Timestamp: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP) + "\n\n");
        builder.append("Image Length: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_LENGTH) + "\n");
        builder.append("Image Width: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH) + "\n\n");
        builder.append("Camera Make: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE) + "\n");
        builder.append("Camera Model: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL) + "\n");
        builder.append("Camera Orientation: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION) + "\n");
        builder.append("Camera White Balance: " + getExifTag(exif,ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_BALANCE) + "\n");         
        builder = null;
     }
     catch (IOException e) 
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }                       

}
```

code to capture photo

```
Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                 fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
                 captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name
                startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how to send the photo as argument?" You should have the filepath to your image stored in your fileUri.

Comment: i have the fileUri of the photo. where should I give that?

Comment: what is FILE_PATH_KEY here?